# ASP.NET MVC two calls by button to same view action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have two features on this 'tester' app I have where I am fiddling with ASP.NET for learning purposes.

I have come across an issue with the app. The app has 4 user input boxes, all of which are for mathematical purposes. The first pair take 2 values to multiply, while the second pair take two values to add together.

The issue here is that if I was to multiply values, then add, the multiplied output would disappear (also happens if you were to add then multiply, add would disappear) and I would like for this to not happen. Here's the code if anyone is able to address the issue:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(ExampleModel example, string Submit)
    {
        if (Submit == "Multiply")
        {
            double firstm = Convert.ToDouble(example.multFirst);
            double secondm = Convert.ToDouble(example.multSecond);
            example.multResult = firstm * secondm;
        }
        else if (Submit == "Add")
        {
            double firsta = Convert.ToDouble(example.addFirst);
            double seconda = Convert.ToDouble(example.addSecond);
            example.addResult = firsta + seconda;

        }

        return View(example);
    }
```

and the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.multFirst)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.multSecond)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.multResult)
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Multiply" id="divide" />

    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.addFirst)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.addSecond)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.addResult)
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" id="divide" />
}
```

is there anyway to address this issue? any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your add result and multiple result on a session and retrieve them each time to example.addResult and example.multResult before return view(example)

Comment: Hmm interesting, do you have any idea how I would approach this?

Comment: This actually worked, although with the new ASP.NET MVC framework is different and I can no longer use 'Session["Example"]' for example, approaching it using sessions was the right way to do it, thank you

Comment: With ASP.net MVC framework 4.6.2, I'm doing it like the below code 
 var _scenario = Session["scenario"] as Scenario;

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to change `DisplayFor` to be `EditorFor` like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.multFirst)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.multSecond)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.multResult)
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Multiply" id="divide" />

    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.addFirst)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.addSecond)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.addResult)
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" id="divide" />
}
```

The actual problem is that when you render the page the second time, you use a model that does not have it's `multResult` initialized because the result of the previous computation wasn't stored anywhere except the form itself, and the form won't submit this value back since the respective field is a display field, not an editor one.